# Calling HTML within ASP to call other scripts

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, sharepoint

I'm working on sharepoint and I've embeded jquery, google charts, angular library calls within my file. However, when I need to add or remove things, it becomes a tedious process of going back to SharePoint designer and editing the master page.

This is what I have:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="false" EnablePartialRendering="true" EnableScriptGlobalization="false" EnableScriptLocalization="true">
        <Scripts>
                <%-- Libraries/Addons  Nov27/13 --%><asp:ScriptReference Path="/Style Library/libs/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="/Style Library/libs/jquery-ui.min.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></asp:ScriptReference>
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="/Style Library/libs/jquery.SPServices-2013.01.min.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="/Style Library/libs/angular.min.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="/Style Library/libs/knockout-3.0.0.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="/Style Library/addons/wpToggle/wpToggle-jQuery.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="/Style Library/addons/spCharts/spjs-charts-v4.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="/Style Library/addons/quickLaunchToggle/jQuery.LISP.quicklaunch.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
        </Scripts> 
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

I'm trying to replace this and instead have one html file (or whatever will allow this to work), and instead make to call to that file. 
For example, if I have an html file that contains this:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Script Controller File</title>
 <script type="text/javscript" src="/script1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javscript" src="/script2.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javscript" src="/script3.js"></script>
 <link href="style1.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="style2.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="style3.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
 </head>
 </html>
```

I can change this in sharepoint:

```
        <asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="false" EnablePartialRendering="true" EnableScriptGlobalization="false" EnableScriptLocalization="true">
            <Scripts>
                        something something call Script Controller File
            </Scripts> 
        </asp:ScriptManager>
```

This way, instead of always having to worry about editing SharePoint pages to include the scripts I want, I'd just need to edit the Script Controller file. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a perfect use for LABjs: (http://labjs.com/)

Include a single Javascript file with additional required scripts passed to LABjs. LAB will load them async/sync and add them to the head of the page.

**Script Manager**

```
<Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="/Style Library/libs/LAB.min.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="/Style Library/libs/scriptLoader.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
</Scripts>
```

**scriptLoader.js**

```
$LAB
    .script("/Style Library/libs/jquery-1.10.2.min.js").wait()
    .script("/Style Library/libs/jquery-ui.min.js")
    .script("https://www.google.com/jsapi").wait()
    .script("/Style Library/libs/jquery.SPServices-2013.01.min.js")
    .script("/Style Library/libs/angular.min.js").wait()
    .script("/Style Library/libs/knockout-3.0.0.js")
    .script("/Style Library/addons/wpToggle/wpToggle-jQuery.js")
    .script("/Style Library/addons/spCharts/spjs-charts-v4.js")
    .script("/Style Library/addons/quickLaunchToggle/jQuery.LISP.quicklaunch.js").wait();
```

I'm not 100% sure which scripts need to be synchronously loaded. .wait() tells LAB to not make any more script requests until everything before .wait() is loaded and included.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to check that: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/

It's a new way (with polyfill for unsupported-browsers) that permits to call a single HTML file that contains all the resources.